# Converting from C++ language to C (from class to struct) to use HDC1080 sensor with ATTiny841

Tags: c, struct

Today I'm trying to convert this library: [Arduino library for ClosedCube_HDC1080 Humidity and Temperature sensor](https://github.com/closedcube/ClosedCube_HDC1080_Arduino) to use it with an ATTiny841 [ATTiny841 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8495-8-bit-AVR-Microcontrollers-ATtiny441-ATtiny841_Datasheet.pdf), to do it I'm going to use the Fleury's Library to use the **ATTiny841 as Master** and the **HDC1080 as Slave**.

My problem is that I have some issues to convert from the **C++ language** that is used in the **HDC1080 library** for Arduino to the **ATTiny**, which use **C language**, for that I would show you header files to explain myself.

```
HDC1080_Registers;

class ClosedCube_HDC1080 {
public:
    ClosedCube_HDC1080();

    void begin(uint8_t address);
    uint16_t readManufacturerId(); // 0x5449 ID of Texas Instruments
    uint16_t readDeviceId(); // 0x1050 ID of the device

    HDC1080_Registers readRegister();   
    void writeRegister(HDC1080_Registers reg);

    void heatUp(uint8_t seconds);

    float readTemperature();
    float readHumidity();

    float readT(); // short-cut for readTemperature
    float readH(); // short-cut for readHumidity

private:
    uint8_t _address;
    uint16_t readData(uint8_t pointer);

};

#endif
```

This is from the header (.h) file of HDC1080 sensor, I read that class function is not available in C language, so I decide to use struct function, which I saw that is available in C language, but in examples that I saw on Internet, they only use struct function to declare variables, and functions not like:

- ClosedCube_HDC1080();
- void begin(uint8_t address);
- HDC1080_Registers readRegister();
- void writeRegister(HDC1080_Registers reg);
- void heatUp(uint8_t seconds);

They are define it outside of the struct function, so I get confused with those void's which are inside of the class function, this is reason why I looking for some help. I just need to know:

- How to declare those functions to work with the **struct**
- Is going to be much easier to define them later in the C (.c) file?

Thanks for your time and your patience, is my first time converting from one language to another.

Comment: Yeah.. you are going to have to explicitly pass a struct instance into those functions as an argument, (or a pointer to one).

Comment: The only state the HDC1080 has is just the address, so rather than put it in a struct, just implement the functions with the address as a first parameter, and prepend `HDC1080_` to function names to prevent conflicts with other functions. So, for example, `HDC1080_Registers hdc1080_read_registers(uint8_t address);`, `void hdc1080_write_registers(uint8_t address, HDC1080_Registers registers);`, and so on. Your main work is the changes needed to switch from Arduino `<Wire.h>` to Fleury's library (whatever that is): it's almost certainly not just replacing function names.

Comment: @NominalAnimal So, let me see if I can understand what you are saying: I have to create another struct with all the functions that I want to define and add them the addres value of the HDC1080 to those who are going to need him, like the ones that you had show me before? like: `HDC1080_Registers hdc1080_read_registers(uint8_t address);, void hdc1080_write_registers(uint8_t address, HDC1080_Registers registers);` ?

Comment: @FabianBarraez: No, I mean no `struct` is needed at all. In a very real sense, adding a prefix like `hdc1080_` to the function names and the `uint8_t address` as the first parameter to each of them (since it is all the state this driver has), is sufficiently analogous to the C++ `class`.

Comment: I see, I will try to do it in that way, I saw in the examples from HDC1080, that they use `ClosedCube_HDC1080 hdc1080;` to replace the whole name with only hdc1080 and now then they only call **hdc1080** to receive any data from the sensor, like: `hdc1080.readTemperature()` or `hdc1080.begin(0x40);` to start communication with I2C @NominalAnimal

Comment: that's why I was trying to get the same thing with C language @NominalAnimal

Comment: Yes, it is commonly done, but it does have downsides (overhead and extra RAM used). In this case, the HDC1080 does not have enough state to justify that extra cost, in my opinion -- especially when you are targeting such a constrained microcontroller as the ATtiny series.

Answer (score 0):

Because the only internal state in that class is a single `uint8_t`, and this code is run on a microcontroller, it is much better to just supply that address as a parameter to each function.

First, note that my suggestions below are derivative of the [ClosedCube HDC1080 Arduino library](https://github.com/closedcube/ClosedCube_HDC1080_Arduino), and therefore licensed under the same license:

```
/*
Arduino Library for Texas Instruments HDC1080 Digital Humidity and Temperature Sensor
Originally written by AA for ClosedCube; this suggested conversion by Nominal Animal
---
The MIT License (MIT)
Copyright (c) 2016-2017 ClosedCube Limited
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
*/
```

ATtinys are small 8-bit microcontrollers, so it's best to avoid using the `float` type. Instead, I suggest you use units of 1/1000 degrees Celsius for temperature (25000 referring to 25 degrees Celsius), and 1/100000 for humidity (50000 referring to 50% of relative humidity).

The interface to the adapted library can be quite simple:

```
void     HDC1080_begin(const uint8_t address);
void     HDC1080_heater(const uint8_t address, const uint8_t seconds);
uint16_t HDC1080_manufacturer(const uint8_t address);
uint16_t HDC1080_device_id(const uint8_t address);
int32_t  HDC1080_temperature(const uint8_t address);
uint32_t HDC1080_humidity(const uint8_t address);
```

If we assume we keep temperature and humidity precision at 14 bits (configured by `HDC1080_begin()`, we don't need the user to set or read the configuration register.

The example code shows that `HDC1080_manufacturer()` should return `0x5449`, and `HDC1080_device_id()` should return `0x1050`.

Since we don't know what kind of interface the "Fleury's Library" has, I shall show the implementation of the above functions with comments (starting with `/* I2C:`) instead of actual library calls.

The `static` ones are internal functions only used by the abovementioned functions, not "user" code.

```
#define  HDC1080_TEMPERATURE      ((uint8_t)0x00)
#define  HDC1080_HUMIDITY         ((uint8_t)0x01)
#define  HDC1080_CONFIGURATION    ((uint8_t)0x02)
#define  HDC1080_SERIAL_ID_FIRST  ((uint8_t)0xFB)
#define  HDC1080_SERIAL_ID_MID    ((uint8_t)0xFC)
#define  HDC1080_SERIAL_ID_LAST   ((uint8_t)0xFD)
#define  HDC1080_MANUFACTURER_ID  ((uint8_t)0xFE)
#define  HDC1080_DEVICE_ID        ((uint8_t)0xFF)

/* Bits 15..8 of the HDC1080 configuration.
   Heater disabled, 14 bit precision for
   both temperature and relative humidity.
   See page 15 of
       http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/hdc1080.pdf
   for other possibilities.
*/
#define  HDC1080_CONFIG_HI  ((uint8_t)0)

static uint16_t HDC1080_read(const uint8_t address, const uint8_t item)
{
    uint8_t hi, lo;

    /* I2C: Prepare to send to i2c address 'address'. */
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits 'item'. */
    /* I2C: End transmission. */

    /* Delay for 9 ms (0.009 seconds). */

    /* I2C: Prepare to read 2 bytes from i2c address 'address'. */
    hi = /* I2C: Read byte. */
    lo = /* I2C: Read byte. */

    return (((uint16_t)hi) << 8) | lo;
}

void HDC1080_begin(const uint8_t address)
{
    /* I2C: Prepare to send to i2c address 'address'. */
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: HDC1080_CONFIGURATION (=0x02). */ 
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: HDC1080_CONFIG_HI (=0x00). */
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: 0. */
    /* I2C: End transmission. */
    /* Delay for 10 ms = 0.01 seconds. */
}

void HDC1080_heater(const uint8_t address, const uint8_t seconds)
{
    uint8_t s, i;

    /* I2C: Prepare to send to i2c address 'address'. */
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: HDC1080_CONFIGURATION (=0x02). */ 
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: 48 (=0x30). */
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: 0. */
    /* I2C: End transmission. */

    /* Delay for 10 ms = 0.01 seconds. */

    for (s = 0; s < seconds; s++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 66; i++) {

            /* I2C: Prepare to send to i2c address 'address'. */
            /* I2C: Send 8 bits 'item'. */
            /* I2C: End transmission. */

            /* Delay for 20 ms (0.020 seconds). */

            /* I2C: Prepare to read 4 bytes from i2c address 'address'. */
            /* I2C: Read byte. (Ignore the value.) */
            /* I2C: Read byte. (Ignore the value.) */
            /* I2C: Read byte. (Ignore the value.) */
            /* I2C: Read byte. (Ignore the value.) */
        }
    }

    /* I2C: Prepare to send to i2c address 'address'. */
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: HDC1080_CONFIGURATION (=0x02). */ 
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: HDC1080_CONFIG_HI (=0x00). */
    /* I2C: Send 8 bits: 0. */
    /* I2C: End transmission. */

    /* Delay for 10 ms = 0.01 seconds. */
}

uint16_t HDC1080_manufacturer(const uint8_t address)
{
    return HDC1080_read(address, HDC1080_MANUFACTURER_ID);
}

uint16_t HDC1080_device_id(const uint8_t address)
{
    return HDC1080_read(address, HDC1080_DEVICE_ID);
}

int32_t HDC1080_temperature(const uint8_t address)
{
    uint16_t temp1 = HDC1080_read(address, HDC1080_TEMPERATURE) >> 2;
    return (int_t)(((uint32_t)20625 * temp1 + (uint32_t)1024) >> 11) - (int32_t)40000;
}

uint32_t HDC1080_humidity(const uint8_t address)
{
    uint16_t temp1 = HDC1080_read(address, HDC1080_HUMIDITY);
    return ((uint32_t)3125 * temp1 + (uint32_t)1024) >> 11;
}
```

Note that the relative humidity range is 0 to 99998, i.e. 0%RH to 99.998% RH. This is not an error, and the formula is taken from the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/hdc1080.pdf) and losslessly scaled to the new range. Similarly, the possible temperature range is -40000 to +124989, corresponding to -40°C to +124.989°C, and this too is according to the TI datasheet, losslessly scaled to the new range. The `+ (uint32_t)1024` term in both ensures correct rounding (to nearest).

You do still need to implementing the `/* I2C:` and `/* Delay` comments using whatever library you have at hand.